Highcharts column chart - First and last column width smaller than rest if pointPlacement is "on" . How to fix it?
When Im using pointPlacement="on"the first and last columns width is smaller than the rest. I believe that the first column moves not to the start of the xAxis but too much to the left and last column too much to the right. How can I give all columns same width? Thanks!
https://jsfiddle.net/J_Code_2025/8bh0kenm/2/

You need to set tickmarkPlacement: "on" and adapt by min and max properties. For example:
  xAxis: {
    offset: 0,
    tickmarkPlacement: "on",
    min: -0.07,
    max: 5.07,
    categories: ["USA", "China", "Brazil", "EU", "Argentina", "India"]
  }


Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kgpzd1t3/
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis

Thank you. When the view size is small (mobile), then the first and last column have still smaller width then the rest of the columns

Hi @Julia, In this case, you can calculate the min and max properties dynamically. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/230n4atd/
